# Plotting derivative of a signal

Tags: matlab, derivative

I am facing a problem in my coding. I have multiple plots in a single fig. I am getting all my plots correctly but unfortunately the plot of derivative is not even visible in the fig. Can anyone please help.. Thanks in advance

```
close all
clear all
clc
load('2019-01-31-structTFMRI-Proband04-Ivan.mat')

fs=structTFMRI.SigInfo.fs; %Sampling frequency in Hz
%PlotLead = 10;
%ECG lead to plot (only used for 12-lead ECG)

%% 12-lead ECG (Outside and Inside MRI)
ECGOutSingle = structTFMRI.ECGMRI.ECG12OutSingle; %820 Samples per beat (~800ms), 120 beats, 12 leads
ECGInSingle = structTFMRI.ECGMRI.ECG12InSingle; %820 Samples per beat (~800ms), 182 beats, 12 leads

%Plot the data
figure; 
hold on
for PlotLead=4:4
    t=(0:1:length(ECGOutSingle(:,1,PlotLead))-1)/fs; %Time vector for plot to have x-axis in seconds
    %plot(t,ECGOutSingle(:,1,PlotLead))
    %plot(t,ECGInSingle(:,1,PlotLead))
    plot(t,ECGInSingle(:,1,PlotLead)-ECGOutSingle(:,1,PlotLead))  %MHD signal

    MHD = ECGInSingle(:,1,PlotLead)-ECGOutSingle(:,1,PlotLead);
    x = 1:length(ECGInSingle);
    [Zi,Zi_idx,Xi,Xi_idx,Bi,Bi_idx] = getZXB(MHD);  
    y = diff(MHD);
    z = diff(x);
    plot(z,y); 
    plot(x,MHD);
    plot(x(Bi),MHD(Bi),'r*');
    plot(x(Xi),MHD(Xi),'g*');
    plot(Zi_idx,Zi,'b*');
end
```

Comment: Are all of the values `NaN`? It's impossible to tell because you've not provided a [mcve], but `NaN` values aren't plotted, so this is a likely diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

You are plotting the derivative of `MHD` versus the derivative of `x`:

```
y = diff(MHD);
z = diff(x);
plot(z,y);
```

Instead, plot the derivative of `MHD` against `x`:

```
y = diff(MHD);
plot(x,y);
```

`diff(x)` is an array with all the same values. Thus, all your values of `y` are plotted on the same location along the x-axis.